# military aptitude test fractions

Tags: fractions

I'm looking to get into the armed forces and have been practicing an online practice test. I'm having trouble with one question. I know guess and check will work but was hoping for a more effective solution.

The question is:
How many soldiers are there in a group of 27 sailors and soldiers if there    are four fifths as many sailors as soldiers?

Comment: Not a programming question!! And Google is your friend, first link I found (I was curious for the answer) https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090408195501AARg8uf

Comment: Sorry thought I put it in math stack. Was wondering why the tags were off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the place for this, but what the hell.

```
Sa = Sailors
So = Soldiers

Sa + So = 27
Sa = (4/5)So
```

Using the substitution method we can substitute `(4/5)So` in place of `Sa`which gives us

```
(4/5)So + So = 27
(4/5)So + (5/5)So = 27
(9/5)So = 27
So = 27/(9/5)
So = (5/9)*27
So = 15
```

There are 15 soldiers and 12 sailors.